# My click event function stop working for some cases and I can't find where do this code fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The purpose of the code is to read the data-target from table rows and compare it to the data target on each div with the class "box". If both data-target are equal I add a class to the [div]which will create a pulse effect using css.

The code work for some of the rows however, for some rows the code will not run at all.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var names = [
    {
      "name": "Cable",
      "location": "7-3"
    },
    {
      "name": "Card",
      "location": "12-4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Computer",
      "location": "69-4"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cpu",
      "location": "69-6"
    },
    {
      "name": "CSS",
      "location": "6-5"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cube",
      "location": "12-3"
    },
    {
      "name": "Disk",
      "location": "39-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Gpu",
      "location": "33-2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Html",
      "location": "62-3"
    },
    {
      "name": "Memory",
      "location": "60-5"
    },
    {
      "name": "Monitor",
      "location": "14-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Mouse",
      "location": "83-4"
    },
    {
      "name": "PHP",
      "location": "74-2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Python",
      "location": "7-2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Pyhton",
      "location": "13-2"
    }
    ];


   var obj = names;
   var tmp = '';
   var mapDot = '';
   var btData = '';
   var id= '';
   var id2= '';
   var addclass = 'pulse';

    var html = "<table id =\"example\" class=\"table table-striped table-bordered\">" +  
                  "<thead class=\"thead-dark\"><tr><th scope =\"scope\">Name</th><th scope =\"scope\">Location</th></tr></thead>";
   $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {

     // Generate a modal Body and a Dot on the map for each object in the array
        mapDot +=  '  <div  class="box" data-name=#' + value.location + ' data-toggle="modal" data-target=#' + value.location +' id=l' + value.location + '></div>';
        btData += '<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"data-toggle="modal" data-target=#' + value.location +'></div>'
        tmp += ' <div class="modal fade" id=' + value.location + ' role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">'; 
        tmp += '    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">';
        tmp += '    <div class="modal-content">';
        tmp += '    <div class="modal-header">';
        tmp += '      <h5  class="modal-title">' + "Details for " + value.name + '</h5>';
        tmp += '    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">';
        tmp += '     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>';
        tmp += '      <div class="modal-body">' + "Name: " + value.name + "<br>" + "Location: " + value.location + "</div>";        
        tmp += '     </div>';
        tmp += '    </div>';
        tmp += '    </div>';

     
        html += "<tr><td class=\"test\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=#" + value.location + ">" + value.name + "</td><td>" + value.location + "</a></td></tr>";
   });


   $(".table-responsive").html(html + "</tbody>" + "</table>"); //append the table to the html body
   $('#example').DataTable(); // convert the table into a data table       
   $('.info_box_sidebar').prepend(tmp); //show info slider on the left 
   $('.map-1').prepend(mapDot); // show each dot in the map

   //when a red dot is clicked add the pulse effect
   var info = $(".box").click(function() {
      info.removeClass(addclass);
      $(this).addClass(addclass);
   });

 
/*When a row is clicked compare the data target to the dots on the map 
if equal add the pulse effect*/

   $('td').on( "click", function() {
      var id = $(this).attr('data-target'); 
      $(".box").removeClass(addclass);

      $(".box").each(function(){
         var id2 = $(this).attr('data-target'); 
         if(id === id2) {
            $(this).addClass(addclass);
         }
      });
   });

//When Boostrap modal is close remove the "pulse" class
   $(".close").click(function() {
     $(".box").removeClass(addclass);
   });

}); // end of document.ready
```

```css
.map{
margin-bottom:30px;
}

.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: #D63134;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display:block;
  float:left;
}

.modal-backdrop {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1!important;
    background-color: #000;
}

body.modal-open {
    overflow: visible!important;
}

.modal-backdrop.show {
    opacity: 0!important; 
}

.modal-content{
  border-radius:0!important;
}

#example_wrapper{overflow-y: hidden;}

.fa-plus-circle{color:#0275d8;margin-right:5px;}

.modal-dialog {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 10040;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 16.70%;
}

.green-bg{
  background: green;
}

body .modal-open {
    overflow: visible !important;
}

.color{
  background-color: green;
}


/*css test*/
.pulse {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #3FBF3F;;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(63,191,63, 0.4);
  animation: pulse 2s infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(63,191,63, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(63,191,63, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(63,191,63, 0.4);
  }
}
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(63,191,63, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(63,191,63, 0.4);
  }
  70% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(63,191,63, 0.4);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(63,191,63, 0.4);
  }
  100% {
      -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(63,191,63, 0.4);
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(63,191,63, 0.4);
  }
}
```

```html
 <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
   
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Map App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 d-none d-md-block bg-light sidebar">
          <div class="sidebar-sticky">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
              <li class="nav-item">
              <div class="info_box_sidebar">
              </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 pt-3 px-4">
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
            <h1 class="h2">Map</h1>
          </div>
          <div class"my-4">
            <div class="map">
            <div class="map-1">
                
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
          <h2>Search</h2>
          <div class="locate">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              
          </div>
          </div>
        
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say the problem occurs from the second page onwards,

try this:

```
$('#example').on( "click", "td", function() {
```

Instead of:

```
$('td').on( "click", function() {
```

Comment: Thanks, This does solve the issue. All because of event delegation.

Answer (score 1):

Often times it is because one binds the event (`$('td').on( "click", function() {...`) before the page is completely loaded, unfortunately that does not seem to be included in the snippets you supply.  Make sure and bind the event once the page is completely loaded by putting the bindings inside the windows load event:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('td').on( "click", function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('data-target'); 
        $(".box").removeClass(addclass);

        $(".box").each(function(){
            var id2 = $(this).attr('data-target'); 
            if(id === id2) {
                $(this).addClass(addclass);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

More importantly, I think you want:

```
<tr>
    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#28-3">Cube</td>
    <td>28-3</td>
</tr>
```

**NOT**

```
<tr>
    <td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#28-1">Cube</td>
    <td>28-3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I just edit the code , if you run my snippet you will see that the code works except if you click in the last one. Any time you click on cube the red box will not listen to trigger event.

Comment: You do see that you have the data-target set to 28-1 in the divs and set to 28-3 in the td's right?  I think it is just a type-o...

Comment: You can use `$(function() {` instead of `$(window).on('load', function() {`. See [jQuery docs](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Comment: @Popmedic it was a mistake , I have updated my code again to replicate my issue. Once I change to the second page of the list in the data-table the events click stop working.

Comment: @FabioS I updated my code to better explain the issue , if you run it ,on the data-table once you get to the second page if you click any of the name the red dot will not change color.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, I would suggest using the click function:

```
$("Element").click(function() {
    // Your code here
});
```

Comment: I believe $('Element').on( "click", function() { }); and the one you mentioned are equivalent. Run my snippet I just updated so you can see my issue. The code works , except when you click on cube.

Comment: They are equivalent, just he is pointing out that if you are using JQuery, might as well do things the JQuery way.  Toe-ma-toe, Toe-mah-toe.